# Creating a 3D Character Model with Procedural Generation

Tags: game-engine, procedural-generation, 3d-modelling

I'm slowly introducing myself into some procedural generation techniques. However, instead of generating a map or level in a video game, I want to learn how to create procedural character models.

I guess something that would be akin to this would be the creatures from the video game "Spore". The basic idea is that the program will choose from a set of pieces of a creature, and piece them together to create one model.

Where can I go to learn more about this? 
Also, do you know of any game engines that may have some compatibility for this sort of project?

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as the *parts* of your creature are static assets and predefined by you (together with the information where the joints and fixpoints are), it does not really matter which engine you use. All common engines like Unreal or Unity allow you to create a character in the game from different components, which would be your creature parts.

The only challenge I see is the problem of animating the creature. You will still need some kind of skeleton that tells the engine how to map the animation to your creature. Maybe you can have different creature *trunks* with skeletons and animation and fixpoints to attach your various parts like arms or legs.